# How may I know my android app's previous Version name/code when I update to latest version

Tags: android

I have developed an android app and I have saved the current version name/code in sharedprefs so that on next releases I would get the previous version name/code every time I update the app so that to handle compatibility issues.

But as the previous versions of the app don't contain this functionality so I can't get the previous version/code and so can't handle compatibility issues.

Does android notify that "xyz" was the previous version of the app while updating to latest version?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you integrate firebase? if yes. then go to firebase console and see them in old events  properties :)

Comment: there is no way to know which version was installed before the update except that you manually implement it. If you didn't implement it in previous version - you can't get that.

Comment: @Tanzeela Nisar, I want to check it inside the app, not on firebase console.

Answer (score -1):

You can get current version name and version code programmatically. You can get the current version of installed apk and check for the version you need. you can get the current version code and name of apk using below code.

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;      //version name
    int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;         //version code
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is not possible if you want to check previous apk version before you install new version programmatically.

Comment: this is not what is asked I believe

Comment: @Karan Mer, I have implemented the same thing which will be useful in next time I update the app. I wanted to get the previously installed version (which didn't have this code) when I update to latest version.